# Which law is true at the transformator?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, power

According to Faradays law The changing flux will generate voltage in the secondary winding/circuit, so if the N2 = 2*N1, then the U2 =2*U1, and according to conservation of energy in that case I1 = 2*I2, till this moment everything is okay, but lets suppose that we increase the resistive load on the secondary winding, that has no effect on the previous laws, but according to the ohms law it cant be happening because the current should decrease, but if the current decrease, the conservation of energy harms, i think.

Comment: Well, actually it's the voltage that is created in the secondary by the ratio of turns of the two windings. Use that and the load resistor to find the current. Then work backwards to find the current in the primary. To check this, think about what happens with the secondary is an open circuit.

Comment: Do you mean increasing resistance of load on secondary or increasing its power consumption somehow?

Answer (score 1):

> lets suppose that we increase the resistive load on the secondary winding, that has no effect on the previous laws, but according to the ohms law it cant be happening because the current should decrease, but if the current decrease, the conservation of energy harms, i think.

If you increase the resistance in the secondary then you will decrease the current in the secondary. Since the current in the primary is proportional to the current in the secondary, the current in the primary will also decrease by the same factor. So the power will reduce by the same amount on both the primary and the secondary side. Thus conservation of energy holds.